# How to check for either of two strings in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Our application uses the following command to find an IP address:

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass "Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 | Where-object -Property InterfaceAlias -eq "Wi-Fi"  | Where-object -Property AddressState -eq "Preferred" | Where-object -Property PrefixOrigin -eq "dhcp" | Select -ExpandProperty IPAddress"
```

I've found this fails on my laptop because the Wifi is called "WiFi" - if I change the command to:

```
Where-object -Property InterfaceAlias -eq "Wi-Fi"
```

it works fine. But how can I check for either of these? I can't figure out how to change the command to something like `Where-object -Property InterfaceAlias (-eq "Wi-Fi" or -eq "WiFi")` - this doesn't work.

Comment: you can either add an `-or` clause to your `Where-Object` filter OR you can use `-match` with a regex `or` - the pipe symbol. something like `-match 'wifi|wi-fi'` looks like it would work. [*grin*]

Comment: As @Lee_Dailey suggested this is indeed working as powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass "Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 | Where-object -Property InterfaceAlias -match 'WiFi|Wi-Fi' | Where-object -Property AddressState -eq "Preferred" | Where-object -Property PrefixOrigin -eq "dhcp" | Select -ExpandProperty IPAddress"

Answer (score 2):

Switching to the regex-based [`-match` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match), as suggested in the comments, is the simplest solution:

```
Where-Object InterfaceAlias -match '^Wi-?Fi$' # matches both 'WiFi' and 'Wi-Fi'
```

<sup>Note the need to use anchors `^` (start of the string) and `$` (end of the string) to ensure that the *whole* string matches; by default `-match` also finds *substrings*. Duplication symbol `?` means that the preceding subexpression (char. `-` here) is matched *0 or 1* time, meaning it is matched, if present, and also if not.</sup>

Also:

- Note that your command's quoting is broken and only *accidentally* works: by not *escaping* the `"` chars. around the (meant-to-be) *embedded* `"` chars. (e.g, in `"Wi-Fi"`, they are effectively *removed* before PowerShell sees them; it is only because PowerShell also accepts *unquoted* arguments in [argument-parsing mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing) that your command works nonetheless.

  - While you can use `\"` to escape the embedded double quotes, a simpler approach is to simply omit them altogether here, or, if quoting is needed from PowerShell's perspective, use `'` (single quotes) for embedded quoting.
- Rather than using 3 separate `Where-Object` calls, you can roll them into one with a single script block (`{ ... }`), joining the conditionals with the `-and` operator; note that the code in the script block below is parsed in *expression mode*, which *does* require literal string operands to be quoted.
- Especially since you're expecting just *one* return value, it is simpler and more efficient to replace `... | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IPAddress` with `(...).IPAddress`.
- As an aside: In the [*Windows PowerShell* CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), `powershell.exe`, the `-Command` parameter is implied when you pass a command string *positionally*; note that in the [CLI of PowerShell [Core] v6+](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pwsh) the default is now `-File`, so you'd have to use `pwsh -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "..."` there.

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass "(Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 | Where-Object { $_.InterfaceAlias -match '^Wi-?Fi$' -and $_.AddressState -eq 'Preferred' -and $_.PrefixOrigin -eq 'dhcp').IPAddress"
```